# Create price matrix from tidy data without for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format

```
     symbol     name        date   close      market
0    BTC  Bitcoin  2013-04-28  134.21  1500520000
1    BTC  Bitcoin  2013-04-29  144.54  1491160000
2    BTC  Bitcoin  2013-04-30  139.00  1597780000
3    BTC  Bitcoin  2013-05-01  116.99  1542820000
4    BTC  Bitcoin  2013-05-02  105.21  1292190000
...
          symbol    name        date     close  market
752109    W3C  W3Coin  2018-04-07  0.000277       0
752110    W3C  W3Coin  2018-04-08  0.000286       0
752111    W3C  W3Coin  2018-04-09  0.000270       0
752112    W3C  W3Coin  2018-04-10  0.000286       0
752113    W3C  W3Coin  2018-04-11  0.000300       0
```

I want to create a matrix with prices and a matrix with marketcaps. Because I'm interested in re-creating the S&P500 index. I have done this with a for loop below. **Question: How do I do this without a for loop?**

*edit: Note that some symbols have different number of dates, for example BTC might have 1000 days but W3Coin only 50 days. I think that is what the error message is telling me.*

import data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data-coins-scrape/CryptoData.csv', parse_dates=True)
cols = ['symbol', 'name', 'date', 'close', 'market']
df = df[cols]
symbols = df.symbol.unique()
nr_coins = df.symbol.nunique()
```

for loop to get prices and makretcaps

```
prices = []
marketscaps = []
shapes = []
for s in symbols:
    # slice out one coin
    dfc = df.loc[df.symbol == s]
    shapes.append(dfc.shape)
    prices.append(dfc['close'])
    marketcaps.append(df['market'])
del dfc
```

check the output

```
len(prices), len(marketcaps) 
# (1531, 3065) is the output 

type(prices[0]), prices[0].shape, prices[0].name 
# output: (pandas.core.series.Series, (1810,), 'close')

df.loc[df.symbol == 'BTC', 'close'].head() == prices[0].head() 
# returns True
```

Comment: Data is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofr3bz5kq91bkvn/CryptoData.csv?dl=0

Comment: You can do a groupby and then store them seperately and at the last append them after installing and resetting the index.. this is what I understand from your problem

Comment: Data new link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j5cu1mrv1pek0ad/CryptoData.csv?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['name', 'date'])
prices = df1['close'].unstack()
marketcaps = df1['marketcaps'].unstack()
```

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: I can't download the file, 404 error. Without it i can't test it, since this code works fine for me in the example you gave. Edit the question with the full data, since that error only should happen if there is a duplicated (name, date) pair.

Answer (score 0):

create a price matrix with pd.concat, some works and some give a type error

```
pd.concat([prices[0], prices[1], prices[2], prices[3]], axis=1, join='outer').tail() 
# works!

pricemat = pd.concat(prices, keys=[btc.index], axis=1) 
# TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'

pricemat = pd.concat(prices, axis=1) 
#TypeError: unhashable type: 'DatetimeIndex'
```

create a price matrix with for loop, give a value error:

```
priced_df = prices[0]
K = len(prices)
for i in range(1, K):
    priced_df = pd.concat([priced_df, prices[i]], axis=1)
    print(priced_df.shape[1])
# at 25 it stops and says:

# ValueError: Shape of passed values is (25, 2057), indices imply (25, 1810)
```

Comment: Add this to your question also..(if you have asked it)

Comment: @Aditya no this is my attempt at an answer